# Serializing Sonarqube issue when mebers are java.util.List type

Tags: java, arraylist, sonarqube, serializable

I have define serializable class and it has members of type java.util.List. In sonar it shows error as "Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable"

But actual implementation of those members are ArrayLists, which are serializable.

```
public class TestDataClass implements Serializable {
    List<String> listMember = new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do make sure to mark the `Collection` fields as **`private`** according to [RSPEC-1948](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1948):

> This rule raises an issue on non-Serializable fields, and on
>   *collection fields when they are not private* (because they could be
>   assigned non-Serializable values externally), and when they are assigned non-Serializable types within the class.

and specify the type instead of using a raw type `ArrayList`, such as :

```
private List<String> listMember = new ArrayList<>(); // notice '<>' for 'ArrayList<String>'
```

Comment: @abo you need to make sure the field is `private` as well